# Confusion regarding Weak and Strong Entity types!

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams, entity

Apologies if this is a trivial question, I recently started studying about E.R. Model. Let me try to clarify my doubt using an example. Consider the two entities,Customer and Loan in a relationship such that;

Customer (Strong Entity):

```
•   Attributes: CustomerID (Primary Key), Name, Address, etc.
```

Loan:

```
•   Attributes: LoanNumber , Amount, Interest Rate, etc.
```

Question 1 : If ‘Loan’ is to be a weak entity here does it necessarily imply that two customers may have same ‘Loan Number’? Otherwise ‘LoanNumber’ can identify the relation.

———————————————————————-

Alternatively consider the following entities in a relation ;

Customer (Strong Entity):

```
•   Attributes: CustomerID (Primary Key), Name, Address, etc.
```

Branch (Strong Entity):

```
•   Attributes: BranchID (Primary Key), Location, Manager, etc.
```

Loan :

```
•   Attributes: LoanNumber, Amount, Interest Rate, etc.
```

Question 2: If ‘Loan’ is to be a weak entity here does it imply that, Customers in two branches or more branches may have the same loan number?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question(s). Making `LoanNumber` unique won't make `Loan` a strong entity. A loan cannot exist without at least one customer taking it, and perhaps without a branch providing it; this is what makes it a weak entity.